# How to evaluate eagerly a sequence coming from grep in Raku?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, raku

I don't understand how laziness / eagerness works in Raku. More precisely how to force eagerness.

I get that Infinite List are lazy. What I don't understand is that some List that have an end are lazy, and why the eager method doesn't work in my case.

I have this example

```
raku -e 'say (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[^100]'
```

which works fine when I want to obtain the first 100 elements. But when I want more, say 200, I can't manage to get these 200 elements.

I know I can iterate over them with a for loop. Like this

```
raku -e 'for (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[0..200] { .say }'
raku -e '.say for (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[0..200]'
```

What I want to do is get the elements with the same functional syntax as above. (the one without the for loop)

I tried those but none works

```
raku -e 'say (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[^200].eager'
raku -e 'say (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[eager ^200]'
raku -e 'say eager (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[^200]'

raku -e 'say (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[0..200].eager'
raku -e 'say (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[eager 0..200]'
raku -e 'say eager (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[0..200]'
```

Can someone please tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has nothing todo with `grep` or `eager`, but everything to do with the `.gist` method that creates a string representation of an object, and which is called by `say`.  Since gists are intended for human consumption, they are intentionally **not** always complete: of `Iterable`s, `.gist` only shows the first 100 elements:

```
my @a = ^100;
say @a;
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]

my @a = ^101;
say @a;
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 ...]
```

There are various solutions: you could use [`put`](https://docs.raku.org/language/independent-routines#sub_put) instead of `say`, which will call the `Str` method, which generally *will* show all elements:

```
my @a = ^101;
put @a;
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Or if you want to get a technically correct representation, you can call the [`.raku`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Mu#method_raku) method:

```
my @a = ^101;
say @a.raku;
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

So, to get back to your examples:

```
put (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[^200];
# 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229 233 239 241 251 257 263 269 271 277 281 283 293 307 311 313 317 331 337 347 349 353 359 367 373 379 383 389 397 401 409 419 421 431 433 439 443 449 457 461 463 467 479 487 491 499 503 509 521 523 541 547 557 563 569 571 577 587 593 599 601 607 613 617 619 631 641 643 647 653 659 661 673 677 683 691 701 709 719 727 733 739 743 751 757 761 769 773 787 797 809 811 821 823 827 829 839 853 857 859 863 877 881 883 887 907 911 919 929 937 941 947 953 967 971 977 983 991 997 1009 1013 1019 1021 1031 1033 1039 1049 1051 1061 1063 1069 1087 1091 1093 1097 1103 1109 1117 1123 1129 1151 1153 1163 1171 1181 1187 1193 1201 1213 1217 1223

say (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[^200].raku;
# (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223)
```

Fortunately, there's a shorter way to get the `.raku` representation: [`dd`](https://docs.raku.org/programs/01-debugging#index-entry-dd)

```
dd (1..*).grep({ .is-prime })[^200];
# (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223)
```

`dd` calls `.raku` on whatever it is given, and also collects some extra debugging information when possible, and prints that on STDERR.

Comment: Re "*Sheesh. Edited within 6 minutes to remove "Hope this helps :-)". Unbelievable.*", I'm not sure why you'd prefer they would have waited.

Comment: @ikegami Most of us didn't sign up to write encyclopedia entries--but to help other programmers (and be helped in turn). Personalization counts ;-).

Comment: @jubilatious1, Did you tag me by accident? I don't see how that relates to my comment. Also, I'm not sure what your point is? One is free to personalize one's answers as much as one wants, as long as one follows the rules. Salutations are explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @ikegami "Stack Overflow is encouraging salutations while not allowing them" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291760/stack-overflow-is-encouraging-salutations-while-not-allowing-them ; "Can we have an official statement regarding greetings, salutations etc. please?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351588/can-we-have-an-official-statement-regarding-greetings-salutations-etc-please ; "How do I make a good edit?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit